# Drag and Drop object to one of the dialog box

Tags: jquery, html

I have a screen where i have story points i.e simple lines of statement > I want to drag those lines in Dialog Box that has been opened after clickin a button.
As u can see in screen .

Want to drag my story into dialog box i.e Iteration 1 that has been opened after clicking "+Create Iteration" button.

Can anyone help me or give any reference ?

[image]

Comment: Please explain clearly and if you tried give codes and what you mean by iteration here

Comment: @sunleo : Thanx for replying . Can you please give ur email id so that i can forward my all codes beacause codes are quite long and that why i'm unable to paste here or any possible solution here.                      And basically Iteration is collection of stories . What I want that to drag these 4 story points to dialog opened . The good thing is that i'm able to drag my stories but its droping behind the dialog box means on the yellow screen not on white screen of dialog box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable). Look for example at the shopping cart demo.

z-index issues can be fixed by properly setting draggable's zIndex option for example:

```
$( "#catalog li" ).draggable({
    zIndex: 10000
});
```

I edited the shopping cart demo to use dialog: http://jsfiddle.net/7683X/

Comment: i'm able to drag but not able to drop as i'm having dialog box . Instead of dropping at dialog box its getting dropped behind dialogbox. Please look forward for your support.

Comment: hi @mechanicalfish : Can u please help me in getting how can i make these vales as sortable . thanx in advance.

Comment: still waiting for your valuable answer  :)